# How to exchange random pixels in an image in Python?

Tags: python, image, pixel

I am trying to write a program that randomly exchanges pixels in an image in order to make it completely new. I am generating two sets of random values for the row and column and then I want to exchange those pixels of the image.

But for some reason, my code just does not do what I want it to. The image looks relatively similar to the original picture but it just looks a bit blurrier.

I want the end result to be the same picture but with some (or all) pixels randomly placed in a different location.

```
     def get_pixel(image, i, j):
     # Inside image bounds?
       width, height = image.size
       if i > width or j > height:
       return None

     # Get Pixel
       pixel = image.getpixel((i, j))
       return pixel

     from PIL import Image
     from argparse import ArgumentParser
     import random as r

     parser = ArgumentParser()

     parser.add_argument("-p",dest="picture",  
                help="write the name of the photo with the file type") 

     args= parser.parse_args()

      image = Image.open(args.picture)

     # Get size
     width, height = image.size

     pixels = image.load()

      ran1 = r.randint(0, width-1)
      ran2 = r.randint(0, height-1)

     for i in range(ran1):
        for j in range(ran2):
         # Get Pixel
         rand1 = r.randint(0, width-1)
         rand2 = r.randint(0, height-1)

         rand3 = r.randint(0, width-1)
         rand4 = r.randint(0, height-1)

         pixel = get_pixel(image, rand1, rand2)
         pixel2 = get_pixel(image, rand3, rand4)

        # Set Pixel in new image
         pixels[rand1, rand2] = (pixel2[0], pixel2[1],pixel2[2])
         pixels[rand3, rand4] = (pixel[0], pixel[1],pixel[2])

        # Return new image
  image.save('lol.png', 'png')
```

Comment: the indentation of the code in your question is very off, please edit and correct it.

Comment: Can you show example input and output?

Comment: I just edited to fix indentation. And an input is just an image and the output should be the same image but some or all the pixels should be in a different location